# Sorting MultiLevel XML using Linq C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to sort XML using Linq but its not working Here is the XML

```
<hierarchy>
  <date>2015/04/01 15:29:10</date>
  <folder name="Root" id="Root">
    <file id="Fukui_R3_20150327182224.xlsx" />
    <file id="BordersTest_20150330144902.xlsx" />
    <folder name="level-1" id="1427455995512">
      <file id="Fukui_R3_20150327182224.xlsx" />
      <file id="BordersTest_20150330144902.xlsx" />
      <folder name="Zxcf" id="1427869724768">
        <file id="Fukui_R3_20150327182224.xlsx" />
        <file id="BordersTest_20150330144902.xlsx" />
      </folder>
      <folder name="Aegh" id="1427869732372">
        <file id="Fukui_R3_20150327182224.xlsx" />
        <file id="BordersTest_20150330144902.xlsx" />
      </folder>
      <folder name="Cfgt" id="1427869741718" />
    </folder>
    <folder name="A-level" id="1427869672074" />
    <folder name="G-Level" id="1427869682304" />
    <folder name="E-Level" id="1427869690384" />
    <folder name="1-A-Level" id="1427869701383" />
  </folder>
</hierarchy>
```

and here is the code I have tried

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(FilePath);
 foreach (var trans in xDoc.Descendants("hierarchy"))
 {
     trans.ReplaceAll( trans.Elements().OrderBy(x=>x.Name.LocalName));
 }

 string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

but it return me same unsorted XML.

Comment: are you saving the `xdoc` after changing it?

Comment: no I haven't saved it yet just seeing result as string

Comment: Aren't the sub-elements of "hierarchy" already ordered by local name?  Their order is "date", then "folder".

Comment: I think the flow should be you take your data in xdoc alter it then again load into the same and save it. this is how it should be....

Comment: Just to be clear, the `Name.LocalName` of `<folder name="Root" id="Root">` is "folder".  Perhaps you want to sort on an attribute named "name"?

Comment: @dbc : basically I want to sort Files and Folders within "Root"

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve... If you want to sort folders by its name, try: `var sortedFolders = xDoc.Element("hierarchy").Descendants("folder").Where(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value=="Root").Descendants("folder").OrderBy(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your code like this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(FilePath);
if (xDoc.Root != null)
    SortXml(xDoc.Root);
string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

and try to use this method:

```
private static void SortXml(XContainer parent)
{
    var elements = parent.Elements()
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.Name.LocalName)
        .ThenBy(e => (string)e.Attribute("name"))
        .ToArray();

    Array.ForEach(elements, e => e.Remove());

    foreach (var element in elements) {
        parent.Add(element);
        SortXml(element);
    }
}
```

This code recursively sort your hierarchy: files always goes after folders and all items are sorted by value of attribute "name".

Comment: Yes it worked but one issue the string this method returns there is no value in date.

Comment: @AdilWaqar, try this: `var sortednodes = xDoc.Root.Elements().OrderByDescending(e => e.Name.LocalName)
        .ThenBy(e => (string)e.Attribute("name"));`

Comment: Adil, you right, **removeNodes** removes **ALL** nodes, including child elements, **text nodes** and so on. I replaced this by Array.ForEach(elements, e => e.Remove()); Now it's work fine.